# cannot get variable to work

Tags: php, variables

I have this code here:

```
<?php   
$search=htmlspecialchars($_GET['load']); 
$method = isset( $_GET['btnAction'] ) ? $_GET['btnAction'] : '';

switch( $method ) {
    case 'Search':
      header('Location: search.php?load=$search');
        break;
    case 'Im Feeling Lucky':
        //do chapter two stuff
      header('Location: search_lucky.php?load=$search');
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Not a valid operation';
}

?>
```

Everything works except the $search variable, I don't understand what is wrong.

Can someone tell me why $search variable dont work when i hit this url: `handler.php?load=keyword&btnAction=Search`

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quotes in your `header` function.

Comment: Why are you **HTML** encoding a string you are putting into a **URL**?

Comment: Quentin, this is for a form that have 2 submit buttons and each one need a diferent action, so i created an handler file that will detect the conrrespondent string generated by each button and redirect to the results. But i needed to keep the keyword string for the final results page.

Comment: @DaniQueiroga — What does that have to do with encoding some text for putting into an HTML document and then putting it into a URL (which is not an HTML document)?

Comment: Dunno man, but its working like a charm for my needs, it might not be the best way to do it, but ive been all afternon searching a way to have 2 buttons in one form with diferent actions and couldnt find any viable php method.

Comment: mario youre right, but i was having also an hard time to find the best sentences for the title of this question, so i missed the related questions. my bad

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your header() function.

`header('Location: search_lucky.php?load=$search');`

should be

`header("Location: search_lucky.php?load=$search");`

as php treats everything between the (')  as literals.  so it's literally passing load=$search

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an if() statement to do it.. see below..

```
<?php   
    $search=htmlspecialchars($_GET['load']); 
    if(isset($_GET['btnAction']) {
    $method = $_GET['btnAction'];
    }

    switch( $method ) {
        case 'Search':
          header('Location: search.php?load=$search');
            break;
        case 'Im Feeling Lucky':
            //do chapter two stuff
          header('Location: search_lucky.php?load=$search');
            break;
        default:
            echo 'Not a valid operation';
    }

    ?>
```

EDIT: just noticed the the 'Search' with capitol S. Change to lowercase might work better.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a little bit broken, so take a look at this after it's changed:

```
<?php   
$search=htmlspecialchars($_GET['load']); 
$method = isset( $_GET['btnAction'] ) ? $_GET['btnAction'] : '';
switch( $method ) {
  case "search":
    header("Location: search.php?load=$search");
    break;
  case "Im Feeling Lucky":
    //do chapter two stuff
    header("Location: search_lucky.php?load=$search");
    break;
  default:
    echo 'Not a valid operation';
}
?>
```

The reason is because you were testing $method (which had a value of 'search') to see if it matched 'Search' (with a capital S). Those two cases do not match, which is why you were seeing "Not a valid operation" output.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, variables are interpreted only in double quotes.

```
header("Location: search.php?load=$search");
```

To use single quote you'll need to concatenate the values

```
header('Location: search.php?load='.$search);
```